# Uncaught TypeError. indexOf is not a function error

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am a rookie and trying to create js script to hide and make visible sections on a webpage. The previous parts seem to be working fine. The last part of the snippet returns this error:

```
scripts.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: sections.indexOf is not a function
    at nextSection (scripts.js:29)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Can anyone tell me what I am not getting here?

```
/*
============================================
array of all sections
============================================
*/
var sections=document.querySelectorAll("section");

/*
============================================
Function to find the section that is being displayed (the one that doesn't have "not1st" as a class.)
============================================
*/

function findSection(){
for (var i=0; i<sections.length; i++) {
    if (sections[i].className.includes("not1st")){
        continue;
    } else {
        return sections[i];
    }}}

/*
============================================
Function to load the next section
============================================
*/

function nextSection() {
   sections[sections.indexOf(findSection())+1];
}
```

Comment: I know the last part is not complete, but I am going step by step trying to make sure every little bit works before I continue with the code.

Comment: because you do not have an array... querySelectorAll is an HTML Collection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array, it returns a `NodeList`. `NodeList`s don't have an `indexOf` function.

You can convert it to an array using `Array.from`:

```
var sections = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section"));
```

...or for older browsers without `Array.from`, `Array#slice`:

```
var sections = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("section"));
```

For more information, see the "For Array-Like Objects" part of my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).